# Method for exporting SAP metadata to Excel?

Tags: export-to-excel, sap-erp

Looking for methods for exporting metadata from SAP ECC to Excel, e.g., table names, table descriptions attribute names, attribute descriptions, etc.

For example, if I use the data browser transaction and display my desired table, I can view the table name (TABNAME), and all of the attributes I selected for that table. I want to export this (something I can do just fine) but, all the descriptions - which I can display by using the performance assistant, when available, as well. This later part I don't know how to do, presuming it's feasible.

Any resources or recommendations would be greatly appreciated - thank you!

Comment: What technology do you use to extract data from "the data browser transaction"? Can't you use it for extracting the "descriptions" too? Maybe you can extract the "metadata" via the data browser by reading the SAP Data Dictionary tables i.e. `DD03L`, `DD04L`, `DD04T`, etc.

Comment: I simply download the table I display in the SAP GUI as a text (tab delimited) file. I found an attribute in the DD03M table (All Fields) with an informal description - it's called DDTEXT. I think this is what I'm looking for. Thank you Sandra!

Comment: You're welcome. DD03M is a view joining the tables DD01L, DD03L, DD04L, DD04T. The column DDTEXT comes from DD04T.